# Determine G-orbits

Tags: group-theory

> Assume that $G = \langle g_1, g_2, g_3 \rangle \le S_{20}$ where
>
> $$g_1 = (1,5)(2,6)(9,13)(10,14)(12,16)(11,15)(14,18)$$
>   $$g_2 = (2,4,6,8)(3,7)(9,17,13,20)(15,19)$$
>   $$g_3 = (1,9,13)(6,10,16)(5,17,20)(7,15,19)$$
>
> Determine the $G$-orbits of $\Omega = \{1, . . ., 20\}$.

Please can someone help me understand what the question is asking. I'm not sure what it means by '$G$-orbits'.

Is it asking me for $20$ orbits? One for each of the $20$ elements of $\Omega$? And if so, do I just put each element $(1), (2), . . $ into each of the $g_i$'s?

Thank you for any help, I'm very confused.

Comment: As your group $G$ acts on $\Omega$, it will move the points around. When they move, the points create "orbits". Two points belong to the same orbit if one of them may be taken into the other by the action of some group element. If the group can take any element into any other element, it is said to be *transitive* and has only one orbit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $G$-orbits form a partition in $\Omega$. An orbit is a set with an element of $\Omega$ and all the elements that can be obtained applying permutations of $G$.

For example, take $1\in\Omega$. If you apply $g_1$, you obtain $5$, so $1$ and $5$ are in the same orbit. If you apply $g_2$, $1$ goes to itself, and if you apply $g_3$, $1$ maps to $9$. So $9$ is also in the same orbit.

Now $5$ maps to $1$ by $g_1$, to itself by $g2$ and to $17$ by $g_3$. $g_1(9)=13$, $g_2(9)=17$, $g_3(9)=13$. $g_1(13)=9$, $g_2(13)=20$, $g_3(13)=1$. $g_1(17)=17$, $g_2(17)=13$, $g_3(17)=20$. Finally, $g_1(20)=20$, $g_2(20)=9$ and $g_3(20)=5$

Then, $\{1,5,9,13,17,20\}$ is a $G$-orbit. Do the same with the remainding elements until you find all $G$-orbits.

Comment: Thank you! So the other orbits are {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18} and {3,11,15,19}?

Comment: Yes, they are. Seems that you've got it :)